# Convert photo name to photo url

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

I have a Place entity with an uploadable photo like this :

```
 /**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 * @var string
 * @ApiProperty(iri="http://schema.org/photo")
 * @Groups({"read"})
 */
private $photo;


/**
 * @Vich\UploadableField(mapping="image", fileNameProperty="photo")
 * @var File
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 * @Assert\File(
 *     maxSize = "1024k",
 * )
 */
private $photoFile;
```

When I request the api I get the photo name of the entity, but I want the photo url (absolute url) to exploit directly in my angular application.
Vich Uploader has an helper to [retrieve the path of the photo](https://github.com/dustin10/VichUploaderBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/generating_urls.md) but I can't do this directly in the method getPhoto(), so how can I do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a [event subscriber](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/events#the-event-system) to do that, listening on the `GET /places` which will look if there is a `photoFile`, do the computing with the helper and populate a non-persisted field that could be called photoUrl.